# Защитить запрос от sql-инъекции при работе с prepare объекта wpdb при запросе по массиву ids

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Работая с объектом `wpdb`, при использовании `get_results` нужно защищать запрос от SQL-инъекций.
Один из способов (точно не знаю, но вроде предпочтительный способ) использовать `prepare`

В своем запросе я получаю записи на основе массива `$entries_ids`:

```
$entries_ids = [1, 2, 3]; //для примера

//пробовал по-разному вставлять через %s, получилось только без %s:
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
  "SELECT ai.id, ai.entry_id, ai.price
  FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}ajax_wpform_entries_add_info ai 
  WHERE ai.entry_id IN (". implode( ',', $entries_ids ) .")"
) ); //так работает, но ведь это незащищенный запрос от sql-инъекции, т.к. данные вставляются напрямую а не через %s, %d, %f?
```

Защищенный ли это запрос от sql-инъекции и если нет, то как его правильно сделать защищенным? Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно не защищенный. внутри IN подставляете плейсхолдеры (видимо %d) по количеству элементов в массиве. А сам массив передаете как второй параметр prepare

Comment: @Mike пока что малоинформативно для меня, т.к. не имею представления как сделать описанное вами, ведь передавать через (%s, %f, %d) можно только строки и числа, а как туда массив передать не знаю. С помощью count я смогу получить кол-во эл-ов в $entries_ids, а дальше пока не придумал. Но спасибо, буду искать

Comment: Речь о том, что нужно сгенерировать строку с плейсхолдерами вида `%d, %d, ..., %d` по количеству элементов в массиве. В запросе посылаемом в `prepare` все параметры будут передаваться через связываемые переменные, так что проблем с инъекцией не будет.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb#prepare почитай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$id_placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($entries_ids), '%d'));
 
$entries = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT ai.id, ai.entry_id, ai.price
    FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}ajax_wpform_entries_add_info ai 
    WHERE ai.entry_id IN ( $id_placeholders )",
    $entries_ids
));
```